# Using Logo to draw sound

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, audio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Logo right now and i'm making a project and basically i want to turn your recorded voice into something visual, only problem is when i go to find code it re that works it requires 1: A picture box and 2: to manually grab the sound .wav file and place it. I already made code to record my voice and to make it into a .Wav file and i already have code to visualize it, just when i run it it appears as a thick square of lines rather than the example i shown. Note: I'm not drawing into a picturebox, i'm drawing directly into the Form by using g.drawline(bleh,bleh,bleh,bleh).

(Example: http://static1.1.sqspcdn.com/static/f/335152/16812948/1330286658510/76_dsc3616.jpeg?token=R1zPNnr9PAoB3WvnDxfFFFvzkMw%3D )

The code im trying to run:

Public Sub DrawSound(x As Integer, y As Integer)

```
    Dim samplez As New List(Of Short)


    Dim maxamount As Short
    Dim pic As New Bitmap(x, y)
    Dim ratio As Integer = (samplez.Count - 1) / (y - 1) 'If there are 10000 samples and 200 pixels, this would be every 50th sample is shown
    Dim halfpic As Integer = (x / 2) 'Simply half the height of the picturebox
    GC.Collect()
    Dim wavefile() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Documents\Sounds\Mic.wav")
    GC.Collect()
    Dim memstream As New IO.MemoryStream(wavefile)
    Dim binreader As New IO.BinaryReader(memstream)
    Dim ChunkID As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim filesize As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim rifftype As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim fmtID As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim fmtsize As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim fmtcode As Integer = binreader.ReadInt16()
    Dim channels As Integer = binreader.ReadInt16()
    Dim samplerate As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim fmtAvgBPS As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim fmtblockalign As Integer = binreader.ReadInt16()
    Dim bitdepth As Integer = binreader.ReadInt16()

    If fmtsize = 18 Then
        Dim fmtextrasize As Integer = binreader.ReadInt16()
        binreader.ReadBytes(fmtextrasize)
    End If
    Dim DataID As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()
    Dim DataSize As Integer = binreader.ReadInt32()

    samplez.Clear()

    For i = 0 To (DataSize - 3) / 2

        samplez.Add(binreader.ReadInt16())

        If samplez(samplez.Count - 1) > maxamount Then 'Using this for the pic
            maxamount = samplez(samplez.Count - 1)
        End If

    Next

    For i = 1 To x - 10 Step 2 'Steping 2 because in one go, we do 2 samples
        Dim leftdata As Integer = Math.Abs(samplez(i * ratio)) 'Grabbing that N-th sample to display. Using Absolute to show them one direction
        Dim leftpercent As Single = leftdata / (maxamount * 2) 'This breaks it down to something like 0.0 to 1.0. Multiplying by 2 to make it half.
        Dim leftpicheight As Integer = leftpercent * x 'So when the percent is tied to the height, its only a percent of the height
        g.DrawLine(Pens.LimeGreen, i, halfpic, i, leftpicheight + halfpic) 'Draw dat! The half pic puts it in the center

        Dim rightdata As Integer = Math.Abs(samplez((i + 1) * ratio)) 'Same thing except we're grabbing i + 1 because we'd skip it because of the 'step 2' on the for statement
        Dim rightpercent As Single = -rightdata / (maxamount * 2) 'put a negative infront of data so it goes down.
        Dim rightpicheight As Integer = rightpercent * x
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, i, halfpic, i, rightpicheight + halfpic)
    Next
End Sub
```

X and Y is the middle of the form. And i also would link where i got the code but i forgot where and also, i modified it in attempt to run it directly into he form rather than a picturebox. It worked sorta haha (And there is so many unused dims but all i know is, once i remove one none of the code works haha) So could anyone help?

Comment: Thank you for telling me

Comment: The image you link to displays a very quick clip of audio ... on the order of a few milliseconds ... I suggest you force the hand of your code to do similar very short clip what way your visualization will more closely match given link

Comment: The code I given draws the audio just like what I shown in the image i sent (this isn't what my code does, it was an example). Its not exactly like it but its in the same style. Just now when I use the code to use the sound, the bars that are supposed to fluctuate are all maxed. Its just box with bars in it. And it couldn't be my audio sensitivity cause I used it on the same unedited code and it worked. I obviously don't have something right haha

Comment: Figured it out. I had to sperate the code and made a filled rectangle in my draw sound

Comment: cool ... do everyone a favor and post as in answer your working code ... so the next person is clued in ... Welcome Aboard SO